problem about a given sequence of positive integers and proving that there exist infinite pairs of satisfying indices
Given a sequence of positive integers ($a_{n}$) satisfying $a_{n} < a_{n+1} < a_{n}+k$ ($k$ is a given positive integer) for all $n$. Prove that there exist infinite pairs index $(i, j)$ such that $a_{i}$ is divisible by $a_{j}$.
A problem with a very short statement and I found it really difficult. To be honest, I don't have any clear direction, I'm simply thinking that if we assume by contradiction that there is finiteness, then there exists $n$ such that for all $m > n$, $a_{m}$ is not a multiple of any any $a_{j}$ ($j<m$), I'm trying to show that now there is a certain number $a_{m}$ where $a_{m+1},...,a_{m+k-1}$ is a multiple of one of the previous numbers $a_{j}$ to show absurd (whether it is related to the Chinese surplus theorem, nah I don't know :(_)
I find this problem quite classic, I would like to discuss it with you, thank you very much

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Doesn't $a_n<a_{n+1}$ imply the part about $k$? Should it be $a_n+k$ instead of $a_{n+k}$?

@Karl yeah, thanks you so much,i have fix it

@DietrichBurde thanks, i will learn :(

The "real" problem occurs to me, which would be to determine whether or not a sequence that meets the given conditions is possible. I think it would be interesting but I lost the enthusiasm to try to solve it.

It suffices to find $k$ terms $a_{n_1}, \dots, a_{n_k}$ that are pairwise coprime, then for any $m$ satisfying $m \equiv i \pmod{a_{n_i}}$ some integer in $(m-k, m]$ must occur as some $a_j$, and therefore is divisible by one of the $a_{n_i}$. But by the Chinese Remainder Theorem there are infinitely many such $m$ and therefore infinitely many such $a_j$.

Even after ensuring that there is no prime dividing every $a_n$, there need not be $k$ such terms: take $k = 5$ and consider all the multiples of $2$ between $1$ and $10$, $100$ and $1000$, $10^4$ and $10^5$ and so on along with all the multiples of $5$ between $10$ and $100$, $1000$ and $10^4$, $10^5$ and $10^6$ and so on.

@ronno I don't think it's right because there's nothing to confirm that $a_{j}$ will be equal to m

@Piquito It's an interesting problem, but thinking about it for too long really takes away the enthusiasm ;(

@ronno maybe it has similarities, i need to look into it, thank you very much

$a_j$ will not be equal to $m$, but it will be equal to $m - i$ for some $i$ between $0$ and $k-1$, and that $a_{n_i}$ will divide $a_j$.

@ronno oh thanks you

@ronno i understand
